Solving Laplace equation using Schwarz reflection
I'm studying Laplace PDE's and my teacher left as an exercise solving to following problem using Schwarz Reflection method:
$\begin{cases}
\Delta u = sen(u), \text{ in } B^+ \\
u(x,0) = 0, -1<x<1 \\
u(x,y) = y^3, x² + y² = 1, y>0 
\end{cases}
$
Where $B^+$ is the positive half disk.
The stated Schwarz reflection says that if $u$ is a harmonic function in $B^+$, then the odd reflection $U = \begin{cases}u(x,y), \text{ if } y\geq0; \\ -u(x,-y), \text{ if } y<0
 \end{cases}$
Can someone help me on how can I apply this statement to solve the problem? Thanks
